# How to Hide and Show dropdown at Same Place depending upon selected values?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, user-interface

I am having 4 dropdowns listed but I want to show only one at a time. It is based on selected values but when I am trying to show dropdown it is not getting replaced by another it just gets visible next to the first dropdown.

I want a dropdown position at the same place only values should get changed. 
how can I achieve this. ?

code :

```js
         document.getElementById("one").style.visibility = "visible";
                    document.getElementById("two").style.visibility = "hidden";
                    document.getElementById("three").style.visibility = "hidden";
                    document.getElementById("four").style.visibility = "hidden";
                 
                 function checklistChange()
                 {
                 
                 if (document.getElementById("productType").value==4068 && document.getElementById("C").checked)
                 {             
                  document.getElementById("one").style.visibility = "hidden";
                  document.getElementById("three").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("four").style.visibility = "hidden";
                  document.getElementById("two").style.visibility = "visible";
                 
                 } 
                 else if(document.getElementById("productType").value==4068 && document.getElementById("S").checked)
                 {
                  document.getElementById("one").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("two").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("four").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("three").style.visibility = "visible";
                 }
                 }
```

```html
         
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p>Product Type : </p>
                </td>
                <td><select id="productType">
                        <option value=4068>Af only</option>
                        <option value=4069>Multi</option>
                    </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p>Plan Type : </p>
                </td>
                <td><input id="S" name="planType" type="radio" value='S' checked="true">StartUp
                    <input id="C" name="planType" type="radio" value='C'>Conversion
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
               <table>
               <tr><td><p>Checklist: </p></td>
                <td> 
                <select id="one" onclick="checklistChange()">
                    <option value=1>India</option>
                    <option value=2>America</option>
                    <option value=3>England</option>
                    <option value=4>SriLanka</option>
                    <option value=5>Bangladesh</option>
                </select>
    
                <select id="two">
                    <option value=5>Africa</option>
                    <option value=6>Nepal</option>
                    <option value=7>Wens</option>
                    <option value=8>Brazil</option>
                    <option value=9>Bhootan</option>
                </select>
    
                <select id="three">
                    <option value=10>Crotia</option>
                    <option value=11>Pune</option>
                    <option value=12>Chiplun</option>
                    <option value=13>Chakan</option>
                    <option value=14>Bangladesh</option>
                </select>
    
                <select id="four">
                    <option value=15>PimpeiChainhwad</option>
                    <option value=16>Pune</option>
                    <option value=17>Paud</option>
                    <option value=18>Mumbai</option>
                    <option value=19>Bangladesh</option>
                </select>
                </td></tr></table>
```

Comment: Elaborate your requirements

Comment: I want to make my Dropdown list dynamic. The values of Dropdown should get changed based on some radio button.

Comment: okay do you want to get dropdown values from the database based on selected value?

Comment: NO. i have received values in List from Database and I have mapped those values in the DropDown list. My requirement is I don't want to show all the values in the dropdown.
the dropdown values should get changed when user select some radio button on UI. I want to make this happen at client side

Comment: There will be Maximum 4 combination will be there. but only 1 will get show at time based on radio button

Comment: use `collapse` instead of `hidden`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use display: none instead of visibility: hidden and display: block instead of visibility: visible. Visibility will simply hide (and not remove) the element. Also you need to call checklistChange when the user actually selects the type of plan they want so your displays update.

There are lot more changes I could suggest to make this more usable, but without being 100% sure about what functionality you want it is hard to say. I also noticed the document's title, so I'm assuming you are relatively new to JS.

```
<HTML>

<head> <title>JS PRACTICE</title></head>

<body>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>Product Type : </p>
            </td>
            <td><select id="productType">
                    <option value=4068>Af only</option>
                    <option value=4069>Multi</option>
                </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>Plan Type : </p>
            </td>
            <td><input id="S" onclick="checklistChange()" name="planType" type="radio" value='S' checked="true">StartUp
                <input id="C" onclick="checklistChange()" name="planType" type="radio" value='C'>Conversion
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
           <table>
              <tr><td><p>Checklist: </p></td>
                  <td> 
            <select id="one" onchange="checklistChange()">
                <option value=1>India</option>
                <option value=2>America</option>
                <option value=3>England</option>
                <option value=4>SriLanka</option>
                <option value=5>Bangladesh</option>
            </select>

            <select id="two">
                <option value=5>Africa</option>
                <option value=6>Nepal</option>
                <option value=7>Wens</option>
                <option value=8>Brazil</option>
                <option value=9>Bhootan</option>
            </select>

            <select id="three">
                <option value=10>Crotia</option>
                <option value=11>Pune</option>
                <option value=12>Chiplun</option>
                <option value=13>Chakan</option>
                <option value=14>Bangladesh</option>
            </select>

            <select id="four">
                <option value=15>PimpeiChainhwad</option>
                <option value=16>Pune</option>
                <option value=17>Paud</option>
                <option value=18>Mumbai</option>
                <option value=19>Bangladesh</option>
            </select>
                  </td></tr></table>
            <script>
                document.getElementById("one").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("two").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("three").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("four").style.display = "none";

                function checklistChange()
                {

                   if (document.getElementById("productType").value=="4068" && document.getElementById("C").checked)
                   {                      
                       document.getElementById("one").style.display = "none";
                       document.getElementById("two").style.display = "block";
                       document.getElementById("three").style.display = "none";
                       document.getElementById("four").style.display = "none";

                   } 
                   else if(document.getElementById("productType").value=="4068" && document.getElementById("S").checked)
                   {
                       document.getElementById("one").style.display = "none";
                       document.getElementById("two").style.display = "none";
                       document.getElementById("four").style.display = "none";
                       document.getElementById("three").style.display = "block";
                   }
                }

            </script>

</body>

</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `visibility = hidden`, `hidden` hides the element but still took place. The other solution you can do to achieve this behavior is to use **display** property e.g:

```
// replace "visibility" with "display" and "visible" with block
document.getElementById("your_id").style.display = "block";

// replace "visibility" with "display" and "hidden" with none
document.getElementById("your_id").style.display = "none";
```